# Is it possible to pass a route parameter to a configuration loader in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, configuration

I have an application that requires some per-tenant configuration. What I would like to do is load configuration for specific bundles using parameters embedded in the route:

```
Route: /{tenantId}/some/resource/390234
```

where I can then load a configuration specific to `$tenantId`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible, since configuration loading in symfony2 happens on compile time.
This means every time you do a

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

or cache warmup.
Why not do this via configuration entries via database? As an alternative, use a custom class to load e.g. yaml files (don't forget caching) with your own configuration.